# Iterability in Python

Tags: iterator, python

I am trying to understand Iterability in Python.

As I understand, `__iter__()` should return an object that has `next()` method defined which must return a value or raise `StopIteration` exception. Thus I wrote this class which satisfies both these conditions.

But it doesn't seem to work. What is wrong?

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.i < 5:
            return self.i
        else:
            raise StopIteration

if __name__ == __main__:
    ai = Iterator()
    b  = [i for i in ai]
    print b
```

Comment: You'll need "__main__" in quotes

Comment: there's a typo. It should be
self.i += 1
rather than
i += 1

Comment: your current code seems to work, is there still a problem?

Comment: Your current version has a space inside '__main__', which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code seems to work.  Instead i'll show you some more iterators/generators.

the simplest builtin with exactly your behavior.

```
Iterator2 = xrange(2,5)
```

A direct translation of your class to a generator

```
def Iterator3():
    i = 1
    while i < 5:
        i += 1
        yield i
```

a generator composed from generators in the python standard library

```
import itertools
Iterator4 = itertools.takewhile( 
                        lambda y : y < 5, 
                        itertools.count(2) )
```

a simple generator expression (not very exciting...)

```
Iterator5 = ( x for x in [2, 3, 4] )
```

Answer (score 9):

Your Iterator class is correct. You just have a typo in this statement:

```
if __name__ ==' __main__':
```

There's a leading whitespace in the ' __main__' string. That's why your code is not executed at all.

Answer (score 4):

`i` will never become greater than 5 if you don't increment it in `next()`

Answer (score 4):

I think in most cases it might be enough to write a [generator function that uses yield](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) instead of writing a full-fledged iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems:

- `if name == '__main__'`:  (missing quotes)
- `def next . . .`: you don't increment `i` anywhere